# If statement inside a print - PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, printing

I need to do a if statement inside a print, i have this

```
while($data=$results->fetchrow()) {
     $id = $data['id'];
     $stuff = $data['stuff'];

print ('  
          <tr>
          <td>'.$id.'</td>'
          if ($stuff == 1){
              print "<td>".$age."<td><td> </td> ";
          }else{
              print "<td> </td><td> ".$age."</td>";
          }'
          <td>bla bla</td>
          <td>bla bla</td>
          </tr>
       ');
```

and this is not working for me, so please guys, help me! :)

Comment: Either use separate `print` statements or use an inline `?:` ternary operator. You can't nest an `if` statement like that.

Comment: @deceze sorry i am really bad at this, can you be more specefic , or give me an example?

Comment: @RodrigoBeloWebdesign check Barmar's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I just moved it outside the print statement.

```
<?php

while($data=$results->fetchrow()) {
    $id = $data['id'];
    $stuff = $data['stuff'];

    if ($stuff == 1){
        $foo = "<td>".$age."<td><td> </td> ";
    }else{
        $foo = "<td> </td><td> ".$age."</td>";
    }
    print ('  
        <tr>
            <td>'.$id.'</td>'
            .$foo.
            '<td>bla bla</td>
            <td>bla bla</td>
            ');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a conditional, aka ternary, expression:

```
print ('  
          <tr>
          <td>'.$id.'</td>'.
          ($stuff == 1 ? 
              "<td>".$age."<td><td> </td> " :
              "<td> </td><td> ".$age."</td>") .
          '
          <td>bla bla</td>
          <td>bla bla</td>
       ');
```

Comment: I believe you need a few more parentheses there to get the correct result. Indentation alone doesn't do it. ;)

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was a reason I usually wrap ternaries in parentheses.